# Compare two UIImages with CC_MD5 in iOS ,but the hash code will be changed after reboot the device

Tags: ios, image, md5

I 've use

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(inImage)];

CC_MD5(imageData, [imageData length], result);
```

for generate **MD5** code of my picture and add them to **NSDictionary** for compare the image from photoLibrary.
But when I add some code or reboot my device , I find the hash code is totally changed .
How can resolve this problem ?

Comment: Did you also try to load directly the file into NSData instead `dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation`? Probably the UIImagePNGRepresentation does different things on different "sessions".

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
CC_MD5(imageData, [imageData length], result);
```

that must work fine.

Also consider to use sha1 as basing algorithm.

Comment: It will still contain the timestamp embedded in the file.

Comment: Yes. But if you compare files instead of compare new generated PNG data FROM a file it should work.

Comment: You are right, it depends whether the files were ever the same: I supposed that the image data in the question might be from some different source since it is stored in a `UIImage` structure.

Comment: Could be, ... then i might end up in serious problems. :)

Comment: thank you ,but if my UIImage is cut by a bigger one ,how can I use "file"?

Answer (score -1):

PNG file format allows to have [timestamps](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter11.html#png.ch11.div.2) inside the binary data. This will be different every time you call `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. I am afraid you can't use MD5 to compare the data of two images this way. Try to extract the raw image data from the files and generate MD5 of the raw data.

Comment: thank you ,I 'll try and tell you the result.I 've tried to run many times or delete the app and run again ,the MD5 has not changed , it 's only changed while I add some code or reboot my device ,so maybe it is not caused by timestamps?

Comment: This is actually not true. Calling `UIImagePNGRepresentation` multiple times with the same `UIImage` will create identical `NSData` chunks.